# similar command for solaris sparc

Tags: java, linux, unix, solaris

```
java -version 2>&1 |gawk 'NR==1{ gsub(/"/," "); print $3}'
```

This works for Linux and Solaris which will return installed Java version in that machine. But it will not work for Solaris Sparc.

Please help me how to get Java version for Solaris Sparc, please give an alternative for this command.

Comment: It should work on Solaris.  You may have awk instead of gawk, though

Comment: Solaris SPARC is just Solaris running on a SPARC CPU.  Make sure your SPARC machine has the same set of packages installed as your other Solaris machines - specifically the package providing gawk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This thread](http://compgroups.net/comp.unix.solaris/awk-substitute-command-doesn-t-work-on-sola/365446) does mention an issue around sub and gsub with awk on Solaris Sparc.

It offers this explanation:

> Solaris `awk` is `oawk` on other systems.
>   Solaris `nawk` is `awk` on other systems.
>   `sub()` & `gsub()` work fine in `nawk`
>
> There is also a standards-conformant awk in /usr/xpg4/bin

So try:

```
java -version 2>&1 |nawk 'NR==1{ gsub(/"/," "); print $3}'
# or
java -version 2>&1 | /usr/xpg4/bin/awk 'NR==1{ gsub(/"/," "); print $3}'
```

The [OP SANU](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3693649/sanu) confirms [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967479/similar-command-for-solaris-sparc/23967593?noredirect=1#comment37083927_23967593) it is working: it was a JDK issue.

Comment: it is not work with Solaris Sparc(It display only command instead of result)                                         root@iwfmvs009:~# java -version 2>&1 | /usr/xpg4/bin/awk 'NR==1{ gsub(/"/," "); print $3}'
command
root@iwfmvs009:~# java -version 2>&1 |nawk 'NR==1{ gsub(/"/," "); print $3}'
command

Comment: @user3693649 your issue doesn't seem linked to `awk`: `java: command not found` means your `$PATH` (for the `root` account) doesn't include `java`.

Comment: I am set my java home path and check about the gawk package. It's there but still it is not working ,please give some alternative which one work in Solaris Sparc

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` is one thing, `$PATH` is another. Do you still see `java: command not found`?

Comment: root@iwfmvs009:~# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0                         root@iwfmvs009:~# java -version
-bash: java: command not found

Comment: root@iwfmvs009:~# echo $PATH
/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0_45/bin:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0_45/bin:/usr/local/jdk1.7.0/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0_45/bin

Comment: @SANU ok, looks good. Can you edit your question and add the commands I mention in my answer, as well as the exact error message that you see.

Comment: @SANU ok, I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 3):

Another way with combination of simple/basic commands,

```
java -version 2>&1 | head -1 | cut -d'"' -f2
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working with Solaris Sparc.     root@iwfmvs009:~# java -version 2>&1 | head -1 | cut -d'"' -f2
-bash: java: command not found                                     please give some more solution on it

Comment: You have include the `java` executable path in `PATH` environment variable. First, find out the `java` path, then include the path in `PATH` variable. Like: `PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/bin" ; export $PATH`.

Comment: I am set my java home path and check about the gawk package. It's there but still it is not working ,please give some alternative which one work in Solaris Sparc

Comment: can you post the output of `echo $PATH` and `java -version`

Comment: root@iwfmvs009:~# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0
root@iwfmvs009:~# java -version
-bash: java: command not found

Comment: @SANU, Try this: 1. `PATH="$PATH":/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0/bin/`. 2. `export PATH` 3.`java -version` . Still if you get error `command not found` error, then try to find out where java is installed in your machine. then, configure the absolute path of java `bin` directory to `PATH` variable and export it as mentioned.